# Outdoor staircase's connector seems to be barely latching on anymore, tips to fix it?

Tags: outdoor, stairs, bolts, fastener, connectors

[image]

I have tried bolting the hexes with a wrench. The lower screw is now tighter, but I have trouble tightening the first one as the connector (not sure what this fastener is supposed to be called) looks like it can come off any minute now.

What would be the best course of action to take?

Do I need a full-on replacement for this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you access the other side of the joist? If yes, then remove the lag bolt, and insert a new galvanized carriage bolt, at the other end, use washer and nut. Tighten.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's quite a bit of wood damage/rot. I'd be looking at replacing that section or at least part of it depending on how it's framed.